# Navbar - Need to Extend top and bottom line to 100%

Tags: html, css

I am trying to extend the lines full width of a navbar instead of just covering the links. I think the code/stylesheet  on line 7(include) is interfering with the html style tags below Lines 12-21. However if I remove this line then the background which is dark disappears and the links are displayed as a list instead.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
 <style>

.navbar-nav a {

  border-top:3px solid #DB9842;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #DB9842;
  
}

</style> 
<body>
<div>
  <nav class="navbar-nav navbar-expand-sm bg-dark">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Remove `A` From Your Style Address

You had a border on the `a` link rather than the `.navbar-nav`. The `a` link style will only cover the clickable part, not the whole navigation area.

To solve this, if you remove the `a` from the style, as per the below code, it will span the entire width of the navigation.

```
.navbar-nav {
  border-top:3px solid #DB9842;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #DB9842;
}
```

Because the `.navbar-nav` style is on also on the `ul` element it was creating double borders. To prevent this I added the below code so that the border is only applied to the navigation area and not the `ul`.

```
.navbar-nav ul {border:none;}
```

[image]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
 <style>

.navbar-nav {
  border-top:3px solid #DB9842;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #DB9842;
}
.navbar-nav ul {border:none;}
</style> 
<body>
<div>
  <nav class="navbar-nav navbar-expand-sm bg-dark">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may help you.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
 <style>

.border_color{

  border-top:3px solid #DB9842;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #DB9842;
  
}

</style> 
<body>
<div class="border_color">
  <nav class="navbar-nav navbar-expand-sm bg-dark">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```